# Drone instalation error: level:fatal,msg:main: source code management system not configured

Tags: docker-compose, drone.io

I'm trying to follow the drone [documentation](https://docs.drone.io/) to install drone.

Docker logs drone-server gives me this error

> {"level":"fatal","msg":"main: source code management system not
>   configured","time"

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  drone-server:
    container_name: 'drone-server'
    image: drone/drone:1
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 43:443
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/drone:/data
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DRONE_OPEN=true
      - DRONE_SERVER_HOST=mydomain.com
      - DRONE_RPC_HOST=mydomain.com
      - DRONE_DEBUG=true
      - DRONE_SERVER_PROTO=http  
      - DRONE_SECRET=a5685037ea2e2c12fed551ad033a30b5
      - DRONE_RPC_SECRET=a5685037ea2e2c12fed551ad033a30b5
      - DRONE_GITHUB=true
      - DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT=3a201be47
      - DRONE_GITHUB_SECRET=8adcc6cbc6d

  drone-agent:
    container_name: 'drone-runner'
    image: drone/drone-runner-docker:1
    depends_on:
      - drone-server
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DRONE_RPC_SERVER=http://drone-server
      - DRONE_RPC_PROTO=http
      - DRONE_SECRET=a5685037ea2e2c12fed551ad033a30b5
      - DRONE_RPC_SECRET=a5685037ea2e2c12fed551ad033a30b5
      - DRONE_RUNNER_CAPACITY=2 
      - DRONE_RUNNER_NAME="drone-runner"
      - DRONE_RPC_HOST=mydomain.com
```

I have read this means my github credentials are wrong but I'm certain they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
version: '3'

services:
  drone-server:
    container_name: 'drone-server'
    image: drone/drone:1
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/drone:/data
    env_file:
      - /var/drone.env
    restart: always
```

drone.env

```
DRONE_GITHUB_SERVER=https://github.com
DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=3a2a
DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=8ad9
DRONE_RUNNER_CAPACITY=2
DRONE_SERVER_HOST=http://1.2.3.4
DRONE_SERVER_PROTO=http
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable names look incorrect, for example:

```
DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT=<clientID> 
DRONE_GITHUB_SECRET=<secret>
```

change to

```
DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=<clientID>
DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=<secret>
```

more information : [link](https://discourse.drone.io/t/source-code-management-system-is-not-configured-error/3595)